# Set diagonals of a large array to zero in R

Tags: r, correlation, diagonal

I have a dynamic correlation network as a result of DCC-GARCH. I need to convert diagonals to zero for each array. It is daily data so I have correlation arrays each day. when I type

> print(Corr)

The array looks like this for a day (I can only show a page as only one day fits into the page but I have correlation array for 1000 days) 
[image]

How can I convert diagonals to zero at once?

Comment: The diag() function does the job in one statement. 
     
    diag(Corr) <- 0

If you have multiple arrays, you can use a for loop or a map function to do the same to all arrays

Comment: @Raj Padmanabhan  Thanks for the response. diag() works for a matrix. What I have is large array. it gives this error: `Error in `diag<-`(`*tmp*`, value = 0) : 
  only matrix diagonals can be replaced`

Comment: Are you against `as.matrix()`?

Comment: An array may be visualized a collection of several matrices. You can modify each matrix in the array as described by the following- to set all diagonal entries of matrix 2 in the array to zero, simply write diag(Corr[ , , 2]  <- 0. You can repeat this across all matrices in your array using a for loop.

Comment: @ChiPak,  How can I convert  arrays into matrix without losing any information? I have 1000 arrays and one array is 18X18.@Raj Padmanabhan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Corr <- array( apply( Corr, 3, function(x) { 
          x[ row(x) == col(x) ] <-0; x} ), dim(Corr) )
```

The apply function can work with any of the dimensions, and this will deliver a matrix-"slice" to the inner anonymous function and set its diagonal to zero.

Comment: Thank you very much. It works but the column and row names disappeared. Can we fix it? Also, just curious about `apply( Corr, 3, function(x) ` what does 3 refers to? does it mean apply the function all rows and columns?

Comment: The "3" is index of the dimension that is being operated on. It results in "slices" along that dimension. If you want the dimnames but back just store the dimnames in a temp varaible and re-label the array. `tempnames <- dimnames(Corr); <code above>; dimnames(Corr) <- tempnames`. (The way to deliver thanks is to use the accept-check.)